# How to avoid dowloading apps data using xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I have developed an iPad Application which save user date in both app's Document and Cache folder. Data in the cache folder is highly sensitive. My problem is securing user data. One thing I notice is anyone can plug the iPad to a Mac and use XCode to download .xcappdata file which contains both Document folder and Cache folder. Is there any way to stop this.

Comment: Save then data to your own web server via JSON or XML.

Comment: That wont work because user downloads PDF files which has sensitive data. User should be able to view those PDFs even there is no internet. By saving to a web server wont meet the requirement

Comment: you can encrypt the info, this do not prevent the user from copy the data but will require more effort from him to use it

Comment: It seems there is no way to stop downloading .xcappdata file through xcode.. am I right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need XCode for that. You can use a software like iFunBox to access the apps Document folder.

Instead of turning your app around to use a web service I'd suggest encrptying the data with `NSKeyedArchiver`.

The encoding is done like this:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

Decoding:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

That way you'll have an encrypted file in your Documents folder. I'm using it a lot and it's very easy to implement.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html